# Simple global state for lambda functions

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda

I'm using a lambda function to essentially do some long polling on a device API every 5 minutes to gather data. I also want to be able to trigger the data fetch in real time for testing purposes. I can set the last date time in the API call ... something like `GET /data/?fromDate=$date`

What I want to be able to do is somehow keep track of the last requested time so each time I run the lambda function I get all of the data that has been gathered since the last request whether it was done on a scheduled run or done manually.

Ordinarily I could simply use a variable for this:

```
// set initial date
let lastTime = moment().subtract("5 minutes").toDate();

// lambda function handler
export default async () => {
   const data = await gatherData();
   lastTime = new Date;
   return storeData(data);
}
```

However in lambda each run may be a new process so there is no guarantee that `lastTime` will be kept in memory.

Is there any way for me to keep track of global state in lambda functions for simple things like primitives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to store that sort of thing somewhere outside of Lambda. I've been using a DynamoDB table to store Lambda function global state.

Comment: That's great; can you provide a little more insight / specific example?

Comment: It's basically just a DynamoDB query as the first thing the function does, to get the current state, then a (possibly conditional) update as needed. The update(s) that need to happen, and if they are conditional or not, would be entirely based on your specific use case.